# Pos tagging german texts using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I want to use NLTK to POS tag german texts. I found some references on the web, but most of the are outdated. Some reference for example a "EUROPARL" thesaurus, but it looks like only "EUROPARL_raw" is still available. And that one is not POS tagged. I found also some references to usage of the TIGER corpus, but the latest version seems to be I format I cannot parse with NLTK out of the box.

I'm aware of some non-NTLT alternatives, but I would prefer to use NLTK. Could somebody provide a simple example with POS tagging based on a german corpus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a tagged corpus to use with NLTK.  If you require a pre-tagged corpus you may be out of luck with NLTK.  There is an open issue ticket for this very issue, but there has been no progress ([Reading Negra Corpus Files](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/137))

You could tag your own corpus using the [NLTK Trainer](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and the [Negra Corpus](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/projects/sfb378/negra-corpus/negra-corpus.html).  It would require knowledge of german grammar but no coding.  See demonstration of the [NLTK-Trainer](http://text-processing.com/demo/tag/).

Answer (score 2):

Using the TIGER corpus for training a tagger is a good approach. It's now also [available in CONLL09 format](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/forschung/ressourcen/korpora/TIGERCorpus/download/start.html) which can be loaded with NLTK. I used it in combination with Philipp Nolte's [ClassifierBasedGermanTagger](https://github.com/ptnplanet/NLTK-Contributions) and got ~96% accuracy. I wrote a blog post on [POS tagging of German texts with NLTK](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/07/13/accurate-part-of-speech-tagging-of-german-texts-with-nltk/) that explains how to get this running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TIGER Corpus. It is freely available for research and evaluation under http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/forschung/ressourcen/korpora/tiger.en.html. To import it use ConllCorpusReader:

```
root = '/Users/scott/nltk/tiger'
fileid = 'tiger.16012013.conll09'
columntypes = ['ignore', 'words', 'ignore', 'ignore', 'pos']
corp = nltk.corpus.ConllCorpusReader(root, fileid, columntypes, encoding='utf8')
```

Then use this tagged corpus to train the ConsecutivePosTagger described in http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html. But I only got 77% accuracy. To get better results you might think of other approaches described under *Other Methods for Sequence Classification*.